# IIS Menú Implementar

Tags: servidor, iis, deployment

En el menú contextual de una aplicación en IIS, en un servidor me aparece la opción de implementar, para cargar el zip compilado, pero en otro servidor de iguales caracteristicas y versión no me aparece. ¿como puedo hacer que aparezca?

Agradecido..!!

[image: En este aparece]

[image: En esta No]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te aparezcan estas opciones debes instalar [Web Deployment Tool](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

se descarga de la página oficial de [www.iis.net](http://www.iis.net)

Comment: Esto era. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda =)